# kotlin - android - viewModelScope in singleton viewmodel

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, viewmodel, dagger-2

My application using MVVM pattern and want to use viewmodelscope for the coroutine and now I'm facing some problem related to the viewmodelscope

in the apps, there are two fragments and each fragment has a viewmodel. from fragment one navigate to fragment two and at the second fragment, the user will hit API. if the response is false, the user will back to the first fragment again and need to fix their input. and then the user can navigate again to fragment two and hit the API again.

the problem is at the second attempt, apps can't hit the API because the coroutine is already canceled in ondestroy state in viewmodel at the first attempt (it's automatically canceled since it's the behavior of the viewmodelscope itself CMIIW). and since I make all viewmodel singleton then I guess at the second attempt, the canceled viewmodelscope is called again and cant run coroutine (because it's already canceled in the first attempt).

My question is if I keep using the singleton for the viewmodel, is there any other way to reset the viewmodelscope in the second attempt so it can run again to hit API?

Comment: ViewModels are not global singletons, you need to create a new ViewModel instance every time your Factory is called to `create()` a ViewModel.

Answer (score 2):

1. I suggest you use single ViewModel for your Activity, then all fragments in this Activity will share it, and this is why Google invented ViewModel.
2. This viewModel will follows Activity's LifeCycle, and you don't need to make it singleton, just get it in Activity.onCreate().

Comment: I'm planning to use single activity in my apps with many fragments. If I make the viewmodel to follow the activity lifecycle, is the viewmodel will stay alive until the user destroys the apps?